# How fast is a photoresistor?

Tags: arduino, photodiode, ldr, photoresistor

I am trying to build a skipping rope jumps counter. My preliminary design consists of an LDR, a laser diode, and sn Arduino.

Basically, the LDR and the laser diode are placed exactly opposite to each other, and whenever the LDR detects some obstruction it increments, thus allowing me to count the number of jumps.

My concerns are:

1. How small can the obstruction be? (I guess it depends on the surface area of the LDR, itself.)
2. How fast can I go? (Will the LDR be able to detect a jump frequency of 300+ jumps/minute?)

I would also greatly appreciate it if you can suggest any improvements.

Comment: What are the specs of the devices you are planning to use? Photoresistors have a reputation for being slow.

Comment: Why use a photoresistor over a photodiode or integrated photosensor?

Comment: @mhaselup The LDR module's operating voltage is around 3.3V-5V, and the laser diode's around 3V [link](https://potentiallabs.com/cart/buy-laser-diode-online-hyderabad-india?search=laser%20diode) and [link](https://potentiallabs.com/cart/buy-photo-resistor-ldr-%20light-sensor-module)

Comment: @Hearth No reservations there. If photodiodes work better, I will use them.

Comment: Note: you may wish to pulse-modulate the laser diode's signal unless you're conducting your experiment in a dark room, lest you have trouble with ambient light falsely triggering the sensor

Comment: @ThreePhaseEel I will keep this in mind. Though initially, to ease things out, I will be experimenting in a dark room.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> 1. How small can the obstruction be? (I guess it depends on the surface area of the LDR, itself.)

Yes, LDR tend to collect light from a larger area than photodiodes or phototransistors. A photodiode or phototransistor may include a lens that will focus incoming light to the tiny internal silicon sensor. You can roughly estimate its light-collecting area by the diameter of its lens.

> 2.How fast can I go? (Will the LDR be able to detect a jump frequency of 300+ jumps/minute?)

Where the blocking object is small, it will very briefly block the light source. So speed-of-response is not determined by 300+ jumps/minute, but by that very much shorter moment while light is blocked.

- A LDR is slow-enough that it could miss sensing a briefly-blocked light source.
- A photodiode can sense very fast-changing events. Since photo-currents are small, an amplifier is likely necessary. An amplifier would translate photo-currents to a voltage that an Arduino could detect.
- A phototransistor is slower than photodiode, but is likely fast-enough to detect a small light-blocking object. Since a phototransistor internally boosts photo-currents, an external amplifier might not be necessary. A simple load resistor to your Arduino's DC supply may be all that's required. Some experimentation would be required to choose its value (a large-value resistor increases light-detecting sensitivity).

A phototransistor is a good compromise between speed/sensitivity in this application.

Answer (score 6):

The downside of LDRs is that they typically have a relatively large resistance and also a much larger effective area than photodiodes, making them lazy. If you read the voltage at a simple voltage divider with an LDR, the maximum speed is also dependent on the input capacity of the following stage, because this capacitance has to be (dis)charged through the LDRs resistance.

My suggestion is you use a phototransistor instead of an LDR as they are simpler to use than photodiodes. You can arrange them in a voltage divider just like you would with an LDR, but the phototransistor's resistance changes dramatically under illumination. Phototransistors are not linear like a reverse biased photodiode, which you would use to measure illuminance. But as you only need to decide between two levels of illumination, that's irrelevant anyway.

Answer (score 5):

As an addition to the other answers, typical CdS photoresistors have their maximum sensitivy at green light and nearly none for red and infrared. Also, their sensitive area is very uneven because of the electrode meanders.

That makes pairing a red, bundled light source as a typical laser diode and a typical photoresistor a very bad choice.

Comment: CdS cells are rare now days since they are not RoHS compliant, nothing with them is allowed in the EU, thus they are globally being phased out.

Comment: I wonder what happens if I buy 50 pieces for €5.79 at amazon.de. And yeah, those are CdS. I checked.

Comment: I guess I should be more specific and say nothing sold by a reputable company that actually complies with import laws has them period yes you could still order them from a reseller etc. As raw components

Comment: RoHS does not forbid ithe import of potentially harzardous goods at all. What it limits is the amount of harzardous substances in products marketable in the EU. So you can import as much cadmium into the EU as you want, manufacture a product with it and sell it to outside of the EU. No problem. Or you store it in your mad sciencist's hobby room and build nefarious devices for your own personal use. No problem either.

Answer (score 2):

I missed some quantitative estimates in the existing answers for the question in the title and as I was looking for an answer, I made a simple experiment. I am really a complete beginner in electronics, after doing one-semester undergrad physics lab exercises 20 years ago, so excuse me for using the simple setup using an arduino board. I just set up a cheap photoresistor from a starting kit in a voltage divider circuit with a 10 K resistor and sent the registered pin voltage to a computer using USB.

The first figure shows the time-series of the signal (integers) when I waved my four fingers in front of the photoresistor.

[image: zoomed out]

The second figure shows the modulation caused by the LED lamp generating the light. The frequency is 120 Hz.

[image: zoomed in]

A similar signal from a dimmed LED torch with 140 Hz blinking. The leading edge is quite sharp, but the trailing edge is not.

[image: dimmed LED torch]

My conclusion is that if the object manages to block the light well and the light is of the frequency that the photoresistor registers, than a pulse with a duration of 0.05 s is well registrable.